# AWS Cli command to get "AWS CLI Export"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-emr

When EMR Cluster has been provisioned, I want to get the "AWS CLI Export" output using aws cli command.

Please let me know if someone has an idea to get aws cli export output through aws cli command

Comment: what do you mean by cli export? Did you mean getting environment variable like AWS access key & secret key?

Comment: can you read this blog you will get to know about aws cli export. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/emr-4-3-0-new-updated-applications-command-line-export/  As of now we are able to get aws cli export from UI.  I need the same output from awscli command.